# Converting image pixel coordinates 2D(X, Y) to 3D world coordinate(Quaternion)

Tags: ros, quaternion, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I want to obtain quaternion from x,y,z(depth camera) position. I am new to ros, and I am using Intel real sense.

Things Done:

1. I have integrated yolov5 with ros, and I am obtaining the bounding boxes from that.

> header:    seq: 10   stamp:
> secs: 1608116230
> nsecs: 742268562   frame_id: "detection" image_header:    seq: 0
> stamp:
> secs: 1608116230
> nsecs: 742275953   frame_id: '' bounding_boxes:
> -
> probability: 0.378662109375
> xmin: 626
> ymin: 2
> xmax: 640
> ymax: 64
> id: 0
> Class: "teat"

2. I am getting scaled point cloud.

Think I want to do:

1. I want to find the same location into the cloud point based on yolov5.
2. I want the output like this video:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJWHRW7sZW8&ab_channel=RSAConference
3. I want to obtain the detected object's quaternion so my robot arm can move to that particular location.

What approach I should follow?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367829/converting-image-pixel-coordinates-2d(x,-y)-to-3d-world-coordinate(quaternion)/) by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1622 on 2020-12-16

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure i completely get what your goal looks like, but from what i understand these points could be of interest to you:

- If you want to get the full 3d position of the object, take a look at the `align_depth` parameter and the `aligned_depth_to_color` topics of the realsense driver. This allows you to easily read out the depth associated with pixels in your color image (for more information see [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/286109/getting-depth-data-from-xy-position-of-image-using-realsense-rgb-d-camera/) post). Beware that depth images might just contain some `0`s where no depth information is available.
- In order to get the transform to the object (or only the orientation quaternion you asked for) take a look at the [image_geometry](https://wiki.ros.org/image_geometry) package. It contains classes that can use the information from your cameras `camera_info` topic to e.g. calculate the ray defined by a pixel inside your bounding box (see the `projectPixelTo3dRay()` function). Based on this you should be able to calculate any information you need to plan a robot movement.
- Always useful when working with streamed images: Use the [image_transport](https://wiki.ros.org/image_transport) package to make handling image messages easier.

With these, you should be able to write a node that does this:

- Keeps an `image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel`, and listens to the `camera_info` topic to update it.
- Uses `image_transport::Subscriber`s to listen to both the color and the aligned depth image from your camera and keeps the most current one.
- Listens to your yolov5 output. For every bounding box, you can sample some pixels inside it and read their depth from the aligned depth image, use these to get some sort of "object depth" and then use the camera model to get the object position. In an easy case, you might just sample some points around the center of the bounding box, use the mean of their depth values (filtering out 0s) as depth and multiply the projected ray from your camera model by this to get the 3d vector from your camera to the object.
- Does some fancy visualization, e.g. in your video you can see some custom visual markers to show the object estimation (the yellow cube). I usually recommend using [rviz_visual_tools](https://wiki.ros.org/rviz_visual_tools) for these simple tasks.

I hope this gives an overview over the basic steps required. You might need some simple things like filtering to keep your estimate from jumping around too much (had that happen with realsense depth images before), but this should be apparent once you see your first estimates. If you want to actually move your robot to the detected position you might also need to use [TF2](https://wiki.ros.org/tf2) to get your estimate into a suitable base frame.

If i missed some points from your question or if you have remaining questions, feel free to ask.

---

Originally posted by [RobertWilbrandt](https://answers.ros.org/users/64579/robertwilbrandt/) with karma: 176 on 2020-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2020-12-17**:
Thanks for giving me details it really is a lot for me and my main aim is to identify the detected objects and move my robot arm. I think following these steps will help me a lot.

1. How will I track the object based on the movement of an object. It is tracked automatically or I need to apply another technique for it?
2. Just correct me if I am wrong I have to take the center of the bounding box point that means
   X = (X + X_W)/2
   Y = (Y + Y_H)/2
   and pass this X and Y in the `projectPixelTo3dRay()` function so I will be able to calculate information for the robotic moment.
3. I do not need to find the pose of an object? It will automatically calculate it?
4. Correct me if I am wrong I do not need the Z location. It is calculating automatically by "object depth" is it true? (6 Point of your answer)

**Comment by [RobertWilbrandt](https://answers.ros.org/users/64579/robertwilbrandt/) on 2020-12-17**:
Hey,

1. I am not quite sure what you mean by "tracking". The node (in the form i described it) would constantly update its estimate of the object position. In most cases you would just publish that as a tf (using a [tf2_ros](https://wiki.ros.org/tf2_ros) `TransformBroadcaster`. This way, you could create another node to handle the the actual robot movement (getting its target using a `tf2_ros::TransformListener` from your first node) without having to care about how to get the position estimate.
2. That's correct, for the message you described (the one from yolov5) you would just use `[(xmin+xmax)/2, (ymin+ymax)/2]`. This might not get the best results for some objects (imagine something like a donut with a hole in the middle: Using the center point to calculate the depth will give you unusable results), but for many simple objects like the one in the video this should be fine.

**Comment by [RobertWilbrandt](https://answers.ros.org/users/64579/robertwilbrandt/) on 2020-12-17**:
3./4. What would automatically calculate it? The `projectPixelTo3dRay()` function will give you a vector with `z=1` (as described in [the documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/image_geometry/html/c++/classimage__geometry_1_1PinholeCameraModel.html#a40ad5d3b964d63f41232428fb96376fe). This vector only points into the correct direction, but you still need to scale it to get the actual position of the object. This is why you need to read the depth value from the aligned depth image. Given the direction vector `v=(v_x,v_y,1)` from the `projectPixelToRay()` function and a depth of `d` from the aligned depth image, `d * v` will give you the position of the object relative to the camera.

In general: This will only give you a position (as opposed to a pose, which typically also includes an orientation) relative to the camera. You typically use `TF2` to convert this into a position relative to the robot base, which can then be used to control a robot.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2020-12-18**:
Thanks for the reply and for clarifying my points

Actually, my use-case for my project is to make a robotic milking system just like lely: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ahez-7cDdM&t=97s&ab_channel=Killercrock88

Until now I have just identified bounding boxes in ros and Now I will use your steps I will be able to achieve my use-case?

**Comment by [RobertWilbrandt](https://answers.ros.org/users/64579/robertwilbrandt/) on 2020-12-21**:
Hey, that actually sounds like a really interesting use case. I think the general procedure should work, but just a few considerations:

- Make sure you consider the minimum range of the realsense, i.e. test whether you actually get usable depth information out of it in the position you plan to mount it. Under a certain distance (depending on the specific model) you will just get zeroes.
- If you plan to move the robot in a compliant way, it might make sense to just ignore the depth given by realsense for the control. This would mean: You still calculate the target point with the depth data, but ignore the z-coordinate of the resulting point for your actual arm movement. This might make your approach more robust, but obviously only if you have some way to measure the force on your end effectors.

Apart from that i don't really have any insights into this, my applications were always in a much more structured environment :). Good luck, this seems like a really interesting application.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2020-12-22**:
Hey,

Thank you so much for help will try this and give you update

thanks

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-01-04**:
Hey Robert,

Correct me if I am wrong, from your answer 3 points:  Always useful when working with streamed images: Use the image_transport package to make handling image messages easier.

A. Here I have to take 3 channels:

1. Depth channels- /camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw
2. Color channels - /camera/color/image_raw
3. detected object channels: /darknet_ros/detection_image (Just a color channels with bounding boxes on the detected object)

Compress these three channels using [Image_transport](https://wiki.ros.org/image_transport). Over here I can directly compress by using this command in the launch file? [Example 1 in this link](https://answers.ros.org/question/12216/launch-file-how-to-write-it/)

```
rosrun image_transport republish raw in:=camera/image out:=camera/image_repub
```

Just like this in launch file:

```
 <node name="depth_republish" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" output="screen" args="raw in:=/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw out:=/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/comp_image_raw" />
    
 <node name="color_republish" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" output="screen" args="compressed in:=/camera/color/image_raw raw out:=/camera/color/comp_image_raw" />
```

Or I have to write a C++ code for it?

B.  For detecting objects I should use compressed Images or not?

Thanks in advance for clarifying my small doubt.

**Comment by [RobertWilbrandt](https://answers.ros.org/users/64579/robertwilbrandt/) on 2021-01-06**:
@Ranjit the `image_transport` was strictly targeting your c++ code, you don't need any `republisher` node in this setup. You would use the provided `image_transport::ImageTransport` class in your custom node for receiving the camera images, take a look at [these usage instructions](https://wiki.ros.org/image_transport#C.2B-.2B-_Usage) or [this tutorial](https://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/SubscribingToImages). The big advantage of this is that you don't actually care about the specific image transport (such as compression strategy), as this is transparently handled for you. You would use one instance of this class for each image you want to receive.

As for your 3 channels listed: Are you sure you need to listen to your `/darknet_ros/detection_image`? For all the calculations a simple subscriber to the associated `bounding_boxes` topic should suffice (ignore this if you want to use it for debugging purposes, that might still make a lot of sense).

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-01-06**:
@RobertWilbrandt,

I have understood is correct or not please Correct me,

1. `Image_transport` Side

Step 1. Write a node in C++ that Subscribe to two channels  1. Depth channels (/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw) and 2. Color channels (/camera/color/image_raw).

Step 2: Then use `image_transport::ImageTransport()` class and publish the compressed version of both channels.

2. `image_geometry` Side

Step 1: Create a Node in Python and subscribe to both compressed (Color and Depth) and `camera_info` channels.

Step 2: Use `camera_Info` information to update `image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel()` at the time of initialization. Note: this will execute only one time.

Step 3: Calculating centroid of the bounding box [(xmin+xmax)/2, (ymin+ymax)/2]. Take care of the center of depth value pixel value, not 0. If it is try to use another pixel that is near to that 0 pixels.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-01-06**:
Step 4. Now pass X,Y of the center of bounding box to this function `projectPixelToRay((X, Y))` I will get a vector as an output whose Z value is 1.

Step 5: A depth of d from the aligned depth channels(Image), d * v will give you the position of the object relative to the camera.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-01-06**:
3) `tf2_ros` side:I am not cleared about this flow, but I am trying my best to understand it.

Step 1: Continuously publish estimation pose for a detected object via `TransformBroadcaster()` function.

Step 2: This way, you could create another node to handle the actual robot movement (getting its target using a `tf2_ros::TransformListener` from your first node) without having to care about how to get the position estimate.

4. Moveit package:

Step 1.  for robot navigation purposes based on the data I will receive from tf.

These 1,2,3,4, points should be sequence-wise to achieve my objective right?
Can you please! confirm that my understanding of building this use-case is correct or wrong?

Thank you so much for helping me out.

**Comment by [RobertWilbrandt](https://answers.ros.org/users/64579/robertwilbrandt/) on 2021-01-10**:
Hey @Ranjit, some minor points:

You don't publish any images here. Just think of `image_transport::Subscriber` as a more "intelligent" form of `ros::Subscriber`. This means you would have your 1,2 and 3 steps all in one node. This node listens to the color- and depth image using `image_transport::Subscriber` and `camera_info` using a normal one. The "output" of this node would be the TF transformation (from `tf2_ros`). This also has other advantages - You can e.g. use rviz for debugging (as it can show you your published tf transform).

Otherwise this seems correct.

**Comment by [TapleFlib](https://answers.ros.org/users/144407/tapleflib/) on 2023-04-22**:
Hello, can you share your code ? thankyou !

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The final answer for this question is here with compare of depth and point cloud technique.

A) Image_transport Side
Step 1. Write a node in C++ that Subscribe to two channels 1. Depth channels (/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw) and 2. Color channels (/camera/color/image_raw).

Step 2: Then use `image_transport::ImageTransport()` class and publish the compressed version of both channels.

B) image_geometry Side

Step 1: Create a Node in Python and subscribe to both compressed (Color and Depth) and camera_info channels.

Step 2: Use camera_Info information to update `image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel()` at the time of initialization. Note: this will execute only one time.

Step 3: Calculating centroid of the bounding box `[(xmin+xmax)/2, (ymin+ymax)/2].` Take care of the center of depth value pixel value, not 0. If it is, try to use another pixel that is near to that 0 pixels.

Step 4. Now pass X, Y of the center of the bounding box to this function `projectPixelToRay((X, Y))`. I will get a vector as an output whose Z value is

Step 5: A depth of d from the aligned depth channels(Image), d * v, will give you the object's position relative to the camera.

Note: Over here, try to use point cloud instead of depth channel. I have compared the results of both and finally can tell that point cloud gives the proper Z then aligned depth. Moreover, a depth channel gives null coordinates more than a point cloud.

C) tf2_ros side: I am not cleared about this flow, but I am trying my best to understand it.

Step 1: Continuously publish estimation pose for a detected object via TransformBroadcaster() function.

Step 2: This way, you could create another node to handle the actual robot movement (getting its target using a tf2_ros::TransformListener from your first node) without having to care about how to get the position estimate.

Thanks, @RobertWilbrandt, for helping in my use case.

My final output is given in the below image.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-02-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fawkess14](https://answers.ros.org/users/60127/fawkess14/) on 2021-03-14**:
Would you share your code with me? @Ranjit

**Comment by [imousa](https://answers.ros.org/users/71933/imousa/) on 2021-03-14**:
Hi @Ranjit thanks for your post. I am working on very similar project where I detect an objects and track tit using yolo +(some tracking algorithm). I am using the virtual Kinect camera in Gazebo as of now for testing purpose (later I will replace it with Intel realsense or any camera with more range). My approach is:
1-get the centre of the bounding box
2-get the point cloud of that pixel bu subscribing to "pointcluod2" topic
3-get XYZ from point cloud using method "point_cloud2.read_points"
4- use tf2 package to transform camera coordinate to inertial coordinate
I tested code from internet doing up to step 3[(https://www.programmersought.com/article/9245461951/), but not sure if this way is correct since your way is different. Why you did not used pointcloud directly?

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-03-16**:
Hello @umousa,

First things, if your output is perfect, then this can be a way also. No way is wrong, and right it depends on the output.

> 3-get XYZ from the point cloud using the method "point_cloud2.read_points" 4- use tf2 package to transform camera coordinate to inertial coordinate I tested code from internet doing up to step 3[(https://www.programmersought.com/a...,

Can you explain these steps in more depth, if possible? And please attach the link properly.

> Why did you not use point cloud directly?

Reason: For my object detection, I need to use an image stream, so that was the main reason I was using the color channel instead of the point cloud.

**Comment by [imousa](https://answers.ros.org/users/71933/imousa/) on 2021-03-16**:
sorry for the broken link It is [https://www.programmersought.com/article/9245461951/ ]
What I tried to do is matching the the pixel of interest (centre of bounding box) with correspondence point cloud I acquired from read_points method. This will give me directly a 3D point in camera frame of the centre of the object. The issue is I don't know how to associate the pixel to correct point cloud since the datatype of both is different. Second, the transformation from image frame to world frame (I am not sure if point cloud axis is aligned with world frame)
The repo link you attached is great thank you, but I tried using some of the coed but I got this error:
'PointFromPixel' object has no attribute 'depth'
sorry , I don't know how to attach my code

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-03-19**:
Hello @imousa,

> I don't know how to attach my code

Create a new question and attach your code and screenshot and explain in detail what you want as output and what you are getting. I will try my best to answer your question or any person who is more experienced than me will able to solve your answers.

**Comment by [Anukriti](https://answers.ros.org/users/79683/anukriti/) on 2021-10-21**:
I @Ranjit and @imousa, this looks very interesting and actually I need to do something similar. (1) I want to use yolov3 or TensorFlow API to find the center of the detected object (2) get XYZ from these points
can you PLEASE help me? Just in case you have any code for this

P.S - I don't need point clouds or depth

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-10-21**:
Hello @Anukriti,

Have a look at this Yolact ROS 3D  [lightning talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXKLsSK5WBw). I think this will solve your problem. In the case of code, You can also have a look at [depth_yolact_ros](https://github.com/MarkNaeem/depth_yolact_ros).

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-10-21**:\

> I don't need point clouds or depth

You can do it in your 2D camera but your accuracy will be very low. For proper accuracy, you need 3D cameras.

> (1) I want to use yolov3 or TensorFlow API to find the center of the detected object

You can't use Yolo3, TensorFlow libraries to find a particular centre point. You can get the bounding box of an object and then you have to manually find centre point by using your bounding box values for eg. `[(xmin+xmax)/2, (ymin+ymax)/2]`

> (2) get XYZ from these points can you PLEASE help me?

What camera are you using?

**Comment by [Anukriti](https://answers.ros.org/users/79683/anukriti/) on 2021-10-21**:
Thanks alot @Ranjit for the quick reply. I need the X, Y, Z values to feed to the robotic arm for image based visual servoing. Something like this https://robotica.unileon.es/index.php?title=Objects_recognition_and_position_calculation_(webcam) for x, y, z values. I need to do this in ros-gazebo

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-10-22**:
You have not replied to my question: Which camera are you using?

If you are using the only a 2D camera, then it may be tough for you, Otherwise, You can also have a look at [findObject2d](http://wiki.ros.org/find_object_2d) library. You just have to obtain the center point after you get x,y, x+w, y+h points.

**Comment by [Anukriti](https://answers.ros.org/users/79683/anukriti/) on 2021-10-22**:
I am sorry, yes it's a 2D camera. And I think my best way to do it is the findObject2d library? However, here is a paper that mentioned that they use tensorflow API for the same (here is their video https://vimeo.com/258063350)

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-10-26**:
I am sorry, yes it's a 2D camera. And I think my best way to do it is the findObject2d library?

As per my knowledge, I think you have to use the 3D camera when you are using the findObject2d library.

If you want to use TensorFlow, then you just have to publish your bounding box to a channel and you can further process it according to your requirement.

**Comment by [TapleFlib](https://answers.ros.org/users/144407/tapleflib/) on 2023-04-20**:
Hello @Ranjir Kathiriya , I'm new to ROS and currently making a similar project to yours and stuck in the same problem.

- My target :

1. detect door handle and move my robot arm end effecter to the position of the robot arm.

- My software and hardware :

1. ROS : noetic
2. Camera : Realsense D455
3. Robot : Techman robotic arm tm5-700

- My progress :

1. I just added Realsense D455 3d model and the respective tf to robot arm urdf.
2. I wrote a python code where I control the robot arm with `geometry_msgs.msg.PoseStamped()` `plan = arm_group.go(wait=True)`
3. I wrote a python code where I read current pose with `group.get_current_pose().pose`

- My problems :

1. I have no clue which link the `group.get_current_pose().pose` corresponds to, is it end effector or base?
2. I haven't learn how to apply yolo which I will do later (if you know a good tutorial please let me know)
3. I have no clue how to apply tf to convert x,y value from camera to robot arm nor I know how to read the depth val